# java.util.scanner used multiple times

Tags: java.util.scanner

I already have a scanner established in my program.  It looks like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Later on in the program I need to use the same scanner to get more information from the user.  Is there a way to use this same scanner without creating another one?

This is the last question that I have and I need to use a scanner to grab the input whether it is a "Y" or an "N"

```
System.out.print("Would you like to delete this account? (Y/N) ");
        String input = in.next();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) { done = true; }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering when you try to do this?

Comment: I am trying to use the already existing scanner and I am not sure how to call it back up to use it

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to determine what problem you might be having when you try this. At the very least, an error message would help.

Comment: When I try to create a new scanner it says that the variable that I choose is already defined in the main method.  My professor said that you can call the already defined scanner and reuse it, but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: The simple answer is, don't try to create a new one at all, and just use the existing one which is named `in`.

Comment: Ok, but if I try to do that, what would the line of code look like when I try to call it and use it to grab the user's input.

Comment: You would do exactly what you posted in the question, which was why I was wondering what your question actually was. Just use `in.next()` whenever you need more input.

Comment: When I do that it says that the input it say that the variable is already defined in the main method.  This is the line of code that I just tried:  String input = in.next():

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create a new Scanner, just reuse the Scanner that you created. For instance you can use the same Scanner to give values to different Strings based on user input.

Ex:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String first = in.next();
String second = in.next();
```

Does this help?